# The text inside the tables is not aligned

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Simulation parameters} % title of Table
    \centering % used for centering table
    \begin{tabular}{c c c} % centered columns (4 columns)
        \hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
        Parameters & values &\\ [0.5ex] % inserts table
        %heading
        \hline % inserts single horizontal line
            Deployment Area & 1000m * 1000m &\\ % inserting body of the table
        Sensor Nodes or Devices ($\tau$) & 200, 500, 1000 &\\
        Base Station & one &\\
        Initial Energy ($E_{i}$), &52000 mAh \\
        Residual Energy ($E_{r}$) & $E_{i}$-$E_c$\\
        Packet Transmission Power Consumption &91.4 mW& \\ pre-defined threshold ($t_{d}$) & 0.03, 0.05, 0.07. 1.0& \\
        Channel Delay  ($Ch_{delay}$) &  10 milliseconds&\\
        Packet Receiving Power Consumption  ($E_{RX}$) & 59.1 mW&  \\
        Idle Mode Power Consumption & space 1.27 mW& \\
        Sleep Mode Power Consumption & 15.4 $\mu$W& \\
        Transceiver Energy Consumption ($T_{i}$) &1 mW \\
        Transmission Range ($T_{r}$) & 500m &\\
        Receiving Power Threshold ($RTS_{n}$) & 1024 bits \\
        Packet Size ($P_{size}$) & 128 bytes &  \\
%       Hop Count ($H_{c}$) of Base Station & 0\\
            Sampling Rate of sensor nodes & 60 per minute \\
        Topological Infrastructure & cluster-based  \\
        [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
        \hline %inserts single line
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}
```

Comment: Currently, the text in your table is horizontally centered because you used `c` type columns. How exactly would you like your text to be aligned? Please clarify.

Comment: @rsyed please see the answer if this your requirement -- added a strut above and below the header row to avoid contents touching the rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       % Top strut
\newcommand\B{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % Bottom strut

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Simulation parameters} % title of Table
    \centering % used for centering table
    \begin{tabular}{l l c} % centered columns (4 columns)
        \hline\hline  %inserts double horizontal lines
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{Parameters} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Values} &\T\B\\ [0.5ex] % inserts table
        %heading
        \hline % inserts single horizontal line
        Deployment Area & 1000m * 1000m &\\ % inserting body of the table
        Sensor Nodes or Devices ($\tau$) & 200, 500, 1000 &\\
        Base Station & one &\\
        Initial Energy ($E_{i}$), &52000 mAh \\
        Residual Energy ($E_{r}$) & $E_{i}$-$E_c$\\
        Packet Transmission Power Consumption &91.4 mW& \\ pre-defined threshold ($t_{d}$) & 0.03, 0.05, 0.07. 1.0& \\
        Channel Delay  ($Ch_{delay}$) &  10 milliseconds&\\
        Packet Receiving Power Consumption  ($E_{RX}$) & 59.1 mW&  \\
        Idle Mode Power Consumption & space 1.27 mW& \\
        Sleep Mode Power Consumption & 15.4 $\mu$W& \\
        Transceiver Energy Consumption ($T_{i}$) &1 mW \\
        Transmission Range ($T_{r}$) & 500m &\\
        Receiving Power Threshold ($RTS_{n}$) & 1024 bits \\
        Packet Size ($P_{size}$) & 128 bytes &  \\
        %       Hop Count ($H_{c}$) of Base Station & 0\\
        Sampling Rate of sensor nodes & 60 per minute \\
        Topological Infrastructure & cluster-based  \\
        [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
        \hline %inserts single line
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}
```